# Android Facebook SDK 4.0 ShareDialog doesn't show long texts

Tags: android, facebook, share, social-networking, facebook-android-sdk

I am a newbie developer on Android and Facebook SDK. I want to share my long description text content to facebook via Facebook SDK 4.0 on Android.

I have a ShareActionProvider on my App and it's working fine with my ShareDialog method. But I have a long description in my app and I want to share this description on Facebook. I imported and configured Facebook Android SDK and It's working fine with this method;

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

                       Spanned faceKonu= Html.fromHtml(mShareKonu);

                        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentTitle(konu)
                                .setContentDescription(faceKonu.toString())
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.share_onfacebook_url)))
                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.share_onfacebook_image_url)))
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                    }
```

But this method shows my description text too short on wall or somewhere in facebook.

This is my description screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT9rh.png
This is the facebook api when I tap the share on facebook on ShareActionProvider menu : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEPX7.png

H**ow can I post all texts on Facebook like that ?**

**Thank you !**

Comment: No, you can't. You will get max 2 lines for your description. Please limit it to that.

Comment: I can do this in iOS. Are you sure ?

Comment: Are you sure you can do this on iOS? This is what I see on iOS: http://imgur.com/1sSnuBg

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure. Published via Objective C UIActivityViewController no FB SDK imported. http://i.imgur.com/W85mUYP.png and this is the published text http://i.imgur.com/diB1Lo9.png

Comment: The UIActivityViewController actually publishes that as the "status" text, rather than as part of the link (description is for the link url). In this case, it would be considered prefilling the "status" for the user, and would be against Facebook's Platform Policy.

Comment: I just want to post all description message. Actually I don't care url link or something.so can I do that without link like ios on android ?

Comment: Posting anything that the user didn't explicitly type is against platform policy, and can get your app banned.

Comment: Hi Emre. I can see from your this http://i.imgur.com/LpvH9FT.png you managed to post your content on facebook. I have this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311430/android-facebook-4-0-0-share-dialog-does-not-share-the-content, but I could not find a solution for my problem. Could you please put your code for sharing on your fragment.

Comment: I posted my codes in your question gabby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same problem with Android Facebook SDK 4.0. But I found this problem. I use my phone in Turkish. But When I change my phone language to English, problem is solved. That's like a joke. I think it's a bug for now. I hope they might solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to influence the length of the preview Facebook shows for the link you shared. Keep the description brief, for everything else people can click on the link the user shared and read your full message.

As noted by Ming Li in the comments, don't publish this text via any other method as all content in the message field has to be user-generated and typed by the user character by character.

Comment: I used ShareDialog and published my app. But in debug mode I could see my text when I publish my app I don't see anymore. Can Facebook API keys couse this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Predefined text which is not allowed by facebook is supposed to be everything but the text which is typed character by character. This possibly means that we should use open graph stories instead